# Eclipse editor plugin - line numbers and print margin

Tags: eclipse, plugins, editor

I write editor as plugin to eclipse. I write it as extends TextEditor. And I need show line numbers and print margin. I cant find method where to set. Where can I set it? Maybe I extends wrong class.

Edit:
I fixed it like that:

```
public void setFocus() {
    getPreferenceStore().setValue(AbstractDecoratedTextEditorPreferenceConstants.EDITOR_LINE_NUMBER_RULER, true);
    getPreferenceStore().setValue(AbstractDecoratedTextEditorPreferenceConstants.EDITOR_PRINT_MARGIN, true);
    getPreferenceStore().setValue(AbstractDecoratedTextEditorPreferenceConstants.EDITOR_PRINT_MARGIN_COLUMN, 72);
    super.setFocus();
}
```

Comment: If you are extending `org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextEditor` then the editor will be using the settings in the Preferences under 'General > Editors > Text Editors'

Comment: And if I need set it on code?

Comment: Now I find `getPreferenceStore()` that I can set up. But after initialization will be start Eclipse Updater that will be set up general value.